# Optimization problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have a function $ f(x)= \vert x\vert ^3, x\in \Bbb{R^n} $ I have to compute the inverse of the Hessian by using the formula $(I+uu^T)^{-1} = I - {1\over 2}uu^T $, where $I$ is an identity $nxn$ matrix and and unit vector $u\in \Bbb{R^n} $. I have computed the Hessian but I don't understand how it's of the form $I + uu^T$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand your function. It is $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow X$, where $X$ is what? Namely, what is the third power operation on a vector?

Comment: That should be $f: \Bbb{R^n} \to \Bbb{R} $

Comment: So the question still stands, what is your $f$ doing. What is $f(1,2,3,4)$?